# Not sure how to link json 100% in php

Tags: php, android, json, hyperlink

Im trying to create an rss feed that my droid app reads but i have some holes that i can figure how to fix the json link page is http://www.mandarich.com/mandarichServer/mlb/indexbaseball.php when reading the json i can see where the icon is missing on some and cant figure out why. mainly only for citys like ney york and chicago(cities with two names)
and the code i have for the php is as follows:

```
<?php

$teams["boston"] = "bostonredsox.gif";
$teams["nyyankees"] = "nyyankees.gif";
$teams["baltimore"] = "baltimoreorioles.gif";
$teams["tampa"] = "tampabayrays.gif";
$teams["toronto"] = "torontobluejays.gif";
$teams["atlanta"] = "atlantabraves.gif";
$teams["florida"] = "floridamarlins.gif";
$teams["nymets"] = "newyorkmets.gif";
$teams["philadelphia"] = "philadelphiaphillies.gif";
$teams["washington"] = "washingtonnationals.gif";
$teams["chicagosox"] = "chicagowhitesox.gif";
$teams["cleveland"] = "clevelandindians.gif";   
$teams["detroit"] = "detroittigers.gif";
$teams["kansas"] = "kansascityroyals.gif";
$teams["minnesota"] = "minnesotatwins.gif";
$teams["chicagocubs"] = "chicagocubs.gif";
$teams["cincinnati"] = "cinncinatireds.gif";
$teams["houston"] = "houstonastros.gif";
$teams["milwaukee"] = "milwaukeebrewers.gif";
$teams["pittsburgh"] = "pitsburghpirates.gif";
$teams["St.Louis"] = "stlouiscardinals.gif";
$teams["LaAngels"] = "losangelesangels.gif";
$teams["oakland"] = "oaklandathletics.gif";
$teams["seattle"] = "seattlemariners.gif";
$teams["texas"] = "texasrangers.gif";
$teams["arizona"] = "arizonadiamondbacks.gif";
$teams["colorado"] = "coloradorockies.gif";
$teams["ladodgers"] = "losangelesdodgers.gif";
$teams["sandiego"] = "sandiegopadres.gif";
$teams["sanfrancisco"] = "sanfranciscogiants.gif";


$abbr["arizona"] = "ARI";
$abbr["oakland"] = "OAK";
$abbr["baltimore"] = "BAL";
$abbr["tampa"] = "TAM";
$abbr["boston"] = "BOS";
$abbr["nyyankees"] = "NYY";
$abbr["texas"] = "TEX";
$abbr["toronto"] = "TOR";
$abbr["LaAngels"] = "LAA";
$abbr["atlanta"] = "ALT";
$abbr["colorado"] = "COL";
$abbr["philadelphia"] = "PHI";  
$abbr["florida"] = "FLA";
$abbr["milwaukee"] = "MIL";
$abbr["washington"] = "WAS";
$abbr["chicagosox"] = "CHW";
$abbr["cleveland"] = "CLE";
$abbr["detroit"] = "DET";
$abbr["seattle"] = "SEA";
$abbr["sanfrancisco"] = "SFO";
$abbr["St.Louis"] = "STL";
$abbr["chicagocubs"] = "CHC";
$abbr["houston"] = "HOU";
$abbr["nymets"] = "NYM";
$abbr["cincinnati"] = "CIN";
$abbr["sandiego"] = "SDG";
$abbr["ladodgers"] = "LAD";
$abbr["pittsburgh"] = "PIT";
$abbr["minnesota"] = "MIN";
$abbr["kansas"] = "KAN";
?>
```

Comment: use absolute paths for you images eg : `http://www.domain.com/img/1.jpg`

Comment: well most of them display with no problems its just a couple that dont and cant figure that part out.

Comment: I would see if the reason st louis is failing has something to do with the fact that it's the only array key that contains a period.

Comment: slt abbrev now works just had to Cap the S and the L but still cant figure out why certain team icons arnt working

Comment: That's definitely not RSS you linked. It's returning JSON.

Comment: ok my bad yes its json still not sure why some pics show and why some dont.

Answer (score 0):

St. Louis is `st.louis` in `$abbr` and `stlouis` in `$teams`. That's likely what's causing that problem.

As for some of them showing up and some not, I'll bet that your problem is that you're using `team1` and `team2` to look up what the images are. If that's the case, then you've got capital/lowercase issues. Make everything lowercase. On top of that, you've got spaces in `team*`, which would cause issues. So instead of `la dodgers`, try `ladodgers`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: got saint louis working and all code now shows abrrev and on my index php for code it is all lower case but still only certain icons are missing.

Comment: I didnt figure it out just made all prob issue files local takes up litle more space but works.